# $V$ is bounded. Does this imply that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_{a}^{x}\left | f \right |$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am given that the set $V=\left \{ \int_{a}^{x}\left | f \right |:\ x\geq a \right \}$ is bounded. Does this imply that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\int_{a}^{x}\left | f \right |$ exists? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. $F(x) = \int_a^x |f(x)| dx$ is a monotone function, since $|f(x)| \geq 0$. And it is bounded as $x \to \infty$, so it has a limit by the monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; given any increasing sequence $x_n$, convince yourself that the sequence

$$\left\{\int_a^{x_n} |f|\right\}$$

is monotonically increasing and bounded.